# Deletar entidade e todas suas relacões Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Tenho a entidade `Fatura` que tem um relacionamento `OneToMany` com a entidade `Item`.

Quando tento excluir uma Fatura tenho o seguinte erro:

> Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`bd_afunopi`.`item`, CONSTRAINT `FK_26i46vxf33rt1kv9wrwl42t5d`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`fatura_nota`) REFERENCES `fatura` (`nota`))

Eu estou setando o cascade.Type como ALL nas duas entidades, dessa maneira:

**Fatura**:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "fatura", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

**Item**:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "fatura_nota", nullable = true)
private Fatura fatura;
```

Como posso excluir essa fatura e todos os seus itens?

Comment: Como está o método de excluir? 
Dá uma olhada nesse tópico aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146911/hibernate-throws-cannot-delete-or-update-a-parent-row-a-foreign-key-constraint

Ps: Atente pra o comentário que explica o remove: delete(session.get(Employee.class, 10)); 

onde 10 é o ID que ele quer remover.

Comment: @AntônioJúnior era isso mesmo, obrigado. Poste a resposta que eu vou marca-la como correta.

Comment: Opa, obrigado também! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dá uma olhada nesse tópico aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146911/hibernate-throws-cannot-delete-or-update-a-parent-row-a-foreign-key-constraint

Ps: Atente pra o comentário que explica o remove: 
     delete(session.get(Employee.class, 10));

onde 10 é o ID que ele quer remover.